# Who is the Eldest God in Malazan?

Tags: malazan

So, I just finished Dust of Dreams, DoD. I'm left wondering who's supposed to be the eldest of the Elder gods? I've got 3 guesses.

Mael- because the sea is older than anything.

Olar Ethil- because she claims to be the first mother

Togg and Fanderay- because they were gods when only beasts roamed.

Comment: From the main series, I would have guessed Mother Dark, but Forge of Darkness shows that the creation myths given in the main series are pretty corrupted and cannot be trusted.

Answer (score 4):

Having read *Forge Of Darkness* ( not an experience I entirely recommend ) all of the Azathenai are seemingly immortal but also their legends and stories as we have heard them reported in the *Malazan* series are somewhat unreliable. Togg and Fanderay seem to regard many of the other elder gods as relatively young and if they are the first ascended beasts they have a strong claim to being the oldest gods we encounter during the books.

Comment: That's what my guess is, thanks. Is your memory of Forge of Darkness colored by Erikson's tendency to moralize in the third person removed from his character's story lines? Or is Forge of Darkness trimmer and more focused on plot advancement?

Comment: To me it felt like a rambling gothic edifice with very little light in it. There weren't really any characters I cared enough about to want to follow and there was - if anything - even more philosophical discursion, although it was usually given from a character POV. I listened to the audiobook and it was very well read, with a paper copy I might not have even finished it and I _loved_ the _Malazan_ series.

Comment: @SolarCorsaire "Or is Forge of Darkness trimmer and more focused on plot advancement?". Its not. Plot advancement is the last way I would describe that book.